# Get permanent pointer to object in list

Tags: c++, list, pointers, object, boost

I am currently looking for a way of having a permanent pointer to object inside a list. By permanent I mean a pointer that always point to the same object as long as it exists.

I couldn't find any simple way of doing this so does anybody have an idea? I am already using boost so a boost solution is also very acceptable.

To shed more light on what I need, here is an example:

```
std::map<int, std::list<void (*)()> > handlerList; // I store some callback functions like this

void addHandler( int id, void (*handlerFunc)() ) {
  handlerList[id].push_back(handlerFunc); // 100% intended behavior (I know that the []-operator creates a object if it doesn't exist)
}
```

What I'd like to have is something like this:

```
some_permanent_pointer_type addHandler( int id, void (*handlerFunc)() ) {
  return handlerList[id].push_back(handlerFunc);
}
```

And then at some other point:

```
some_permanent_pointer_type handlerPointer;

handlerPointer = addHandler( 123, someFunc );

// Other point of code

handlerPointer.delete(); // or
ListType.delete(handlerPointer); // Or something like this
```

Has anybody any idea? Writing my own class would not be that much of a deal. But I have no idea how to realize this. But I would prefer something already existing. Time and stuff.

Note: This code will be running on a linux machine.

Comment: You can't do this because the list is mutable.  If the list changes, the location in memory of its objects can change.  You can already look up the handler list by id, so you can get it when you need it.  Whenever I see a question like this, I find the best thing to do is to take a step back and ask what you're trying to do, because the answer isn't down this road.

Comment: Are you looking for [delegates?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh755798.aspx)

Comment: @FelixCastor delegates are C++/CX which is different from regular C++.

Comment: @mbgda I don't see any other way for simply removing basically any given handler. Since some of them need to be removed After some time.

Comment: @FelixCastor No since I am writing this for linux.

Comment: @BrainStone, a common solution to problems like this is to return a unique token (usually just an int or uint) that identifies the specific pair of id and callback..  when when you need to delete it, you can say `myListType.Delete(token)` - your list object will find the entry that corresponds to the unique token and remove it.

Comment: @mbgda I think that would work great! Is there any already existing list class that does this in either the standard library ot boost?

Comment: I've seen a trick on SO before that might help you. You could use a shared_ptr and store a weak_ptr in the list. weak_ptr know if the object was deleted or not.

Comment: @Borgleader do you have any examples? i have never worked with these before...

Comment: @BrainStone I put [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1f7f205d8bcba12f) together quickly. Don't judge me ;)

Comment: @Borgleader thank you for your efforts, but the solution of Bill Lynch is better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's something that I've quickly thrown together. Currently, calling `destroy()` twice is bad, but that is fixable.

```
#include <map>
#include <list>

std::map<int, std::list<void (*)()> > handlerList;

class HandleHandle {
    public:
        HandleHandle(std::list<void (*)()> &list, std::list<void (*)()>::iterator iterator):
            list_(list),
            iterator_(iterator)
        {}

        void destroy() {
            list_.erase(iterator_);
        }

    private:
        std::list<void (*)()> & list_;
        std::list<void (*)()>::iterator iterator_;
};

HandleHandle addHandler(int id, void (*handlerFunc)()) {
    handlerList[id].push_back(handlerFunc);
    return HandleHandle(handlerList[id], handlerList[id].rbegin().base());
}

void someFunc() {
}

int main() {
    auto handlerPointer = addHandler(123, someFunc);
    handlerPointer.destroy();
}
```

Comment: But if I remove one object in the middle all the other iterators would be not pointing to the correct entry anymore, would they?

Comment: From the documentation for [`std::list::erase`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/erase): References and iterators to the erased elements are invalidated. Other references and iterators are not affected.

Comment: Perhaps `destroy()` should set the iterator to point to `list_.end()`, and then that could be used to test if this `HandleHandle` has been destroyed already.

Comment: @AaronMcDaid: That would certainly be one way of solving the issue.

Comment: @BillLynch I think you just found my solution. I will test this code tomorow.

Comment: @BrainStone: Likewise, [`std::map::operator[]`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at) does not invalidate any iterators or references to members of the map. So we're good on that front as well.

Comment: One note: `std::next(handlerList[id].end(), -1)` doesn't work without C++11. `--handlerList[id].end()` should do the same, doesn't it?

Comment: @BrainStone: That's equivalent. You could also use (which I just learned about): `handlerList[id].rbegin().base()`

Answer (score 0):

From the requirements you've stated, you need nothing more than

```
using funclist = std::list<void (*)()>;
std::map<int, funclist > handlerList; // I store some callback functions like this

funclist& addHandler( int id, void (*handlerFunc)() ) {
  handlerList[id].push_back(handlerFunc); // Creates list on demand
  return handlerList[id];
}

auto list5 = addHandler(5, &foo);
addHandler(5, &bar);
list5.clear(); // Clears entire handlerList[5], i.e. &foo and &bar.
```